# Send multiple outputs to the same HTML file in Powershell

Tags: html, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

Trying to figure out how to convert to HTML multiple service checks:

I have this script:

```
Get-service -Computername SERVER1 -Name *SERVICE1* | ConvertTo-Html -Body "<H2>Service 1 Check</H2> " -Property Name,Status 
Get-Service  -Computername SERVER2 -name *SERVICE2* | ConvertTo-Html -Body "<br><H2>Service 2 Check</H2> " -Property Name,Status | Out-File  c:\servicecheck.htm
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Check here - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730936.aspx

Comment: I know how to do it, but just not for multiple get-service to output into one HTML file. Thanks though.

Comment: Modifying your question title then.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

May be you can do something like this -

```
$Event = Get-EventLog -LogName Security -newest 100 | ConvertTo-HTML -Fragment 
$Process = Get-Process | ConvertTo-HTML -Fragment 
ConvertTo-HTML -Body "$Event $Process" -Title "Status Report" |  Out-File c:\StatusReport.html
```

**NB:** Replace `$Event and $Process` with your service cmdlets.

`-Fragment [<SwitchParameter>]  Generates only an HTML table. The HTML, HEAD, TITLE, and BODY tags are omitted.`

Reference - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh127059.aspx

Comment: So can I use -Fragment multiple times or just once? Thanks for the help worked great. Will be posting another Q soon if I can't figure it about how to use logic to give an OK or List the services not running and then colour code the response! :)