# Joining two HTML scripts together

Tags: html, powershell

almost identical HTML scripts, each generated by a Powershell script and creates a .html output to a local drive. The output is a table of results following some queries on servers.

Each HTML output file opens up an is formatted as expected, However, I wish to combine the two output files into one script, which will feed into an email as a single HTML message. Please excuse the crude formatting - I have removed the styling from the script for simplicity.

Here is Script 1, which will be known in Powershell as $Table1:

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'> 
     <title>App Report</title> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <font face='calibri' color='#003399' size='4'><strong>App Server Report</strong></font> 
  </td>
  </tr> 
  </table> 

 <table width='auto'><tbody> 
 <td width='auto' bgcolor='#d98880'' align='center'>Server</td>
 <td width='auto' bgcolor='#a9dfbf'' align='center'>Service</td> 
 </tr> 
      <tr> 
      <td width='auto'>Server1</td> 
      <td width='auto' align='center'>Running</td>
      </tr> 
 </tr>
```

Here is the output for Script1, known as $Table2:

[image: Script1]

...and here is Script 2:

```
<html> 
      <head> 
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'> 
         <title>Web Report</title> 

      </head> 

<body> 
      <font face='calibri' color='#003399' size='4'><strong>Web Server Report</strong></font> 
      </td> 
      </tr> 
      </table> 

     <table width='auto'><tbody> 
     <td width='auto' bgcolor='#d98880'' align='center'>Server</td>
     <td width='auto' bgcolor='#aed6f1'' align='center'>Apache Service</td>  
     <td width='auto' bgcolor='#aed6f1'' align='center'>WWW Service</td>
     <td width='auto' bgcolor='#aed6f1'' align='center'>WAS Service</td>
     </tr>
     <tr> 
          <td width='auto'>SERVER2</td>  
          <td width='auto' align='center'>Running</td>
          <td width='auto' align='center'>Running</td>
          <td width='auto' align='center'>Running</td>
          </tr>
    </tr>
```

And here is the formatted output:

[image: Script2]

So now in my PS script I have put both of these into an HTML variable:

```
$HTMLmessage = @"
$Table1
$Table2
"@
```

But the Title for $Table2 is nested into the final td of the previous table. I know there must be a proper way of doing this - I'm not HTML literate, but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16547049/3585278

Comment: Thanks Danieboy - I am already using this cmdlet, but I thought it would be time that I learnt HTML so I don't get too comfortable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see mainly 2 issues:

first: you can't have 2 `<html>` and `<body>` tags, so basically you have to cut out from $table2

second: there are many unopend or not closed tags.

Output of first script has to be:

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'> 
     <title>App Report</title> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <font face='calibri' color='#003399' size='4'><strong>App Server Report</strong></font> 


 <table width='auto'>
<tr> 
 <td width='auto' bgcolor='#d98880'' align='center'>Server</td>
 <td width='auto' bgcolor='#a9dfbf'' align='center'>Service</td> 
 </tr> 
      <tr> 
      <td width='auto'>Server1</td> 
      <td width='auto' align='center'>Running</td>
      </tr> 
 </tr> 
</table>
```

and the **second** one:

```
     <font face='calibri' color='#003399' size='4'><strong>Web Server Report</strong></font> 


     <table width='auto'><tr> 
     <td width='auto' bgcolor='#d98880'' align='center'>Server</td>
     <td width='auto' bgcolor='#aed6f1'' align='center'>Apache Service</td>  
     <td width='auto' bgcolor='#aed6f1'' align='center'>WWW Service</td>
     <td width='auto' bgcolor='#aed6f1'' align='center'>WAS Service</td>
     </tr>
     <tr> 
          <td width='auto'>SERVER2</td>  
          <td width='auto' align='center'>Running</td>
          <td width='auto' align='center'>Running</td>
          <td width='auto' align='center'>Running</td>
          </tr>
    </tr>   
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

(omit `/body` and `/html` if you'll want to add some other outputs)

Now it's your choice how to parse the output to operate the substutions or fix the script to obtain a well format HTML